# C++ RegExp and placeholders

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm on C++11 MSVC2013, I need to extract a number from a file name, for example:

```
string filename = "s 027.wav";
```

If I were writing code in Perl, Java or Basic, I would use a regular expression and something like this would do the trick in Perl5:

```
filename ~= /(\d+)/g;
```

and I would have the number "027" in placeholder variable `$1`.

Can I do this in C++ as well? Or can you suggest a different method to extract the number 027 from that string? Also, I should convert the resulting numerical string into an integral scalar, I think `atoi()` is what I need, right?

Comment: See [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved using std::regex which for some reason I couldn't get to work properly when trying to modify the examples I found around the web. It was simpler than I thought. This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

string FileName = "s 027.wav";

// The search object
smatch m; 

// The regexp /\d+/ works in Perl and Java but for some reason didn't work here. 
// With this other variation I look for exactly a string of 1 to 3 characters 
// containing only numbers from 0 to 9
regex re("[0-9]{1,3}"); 

// Do the search
regex_search (FileName, m, re); 

// 'm' is actually an array where every index contains a match 
// (equally to $1, $2, $2, etc. in Perl)
string sMidiNoteNum = m[0]; 

// This casts the string to an integer number
int MidiNote = atoi(sMidiNoteNum.c_str());
```

Comment: Likely the reason `\d+` didn't work was because you did not escape the backslash character. In C, the backslash is an escape character, so it must be written as `\\d` to refer to the character class: `std::regex("\\d+")`

Comment: You use string iterators to get that _global_ effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in C++, as of C++11 with the collection of classes found in [`regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex). It's pretty similar to other regular expressions you've used in other languages. Here's a no-frills example of how you might search for the number in the filename you posted:

```
const std::string filename = "s 027.wav";
std::regex re = std::regex("[0-9]+");
std::smatch matches;

if (std::regex_search(filename, matches, re)) {
        std::cout << matches.size() << " matches." << std::endl;
        for (auto &match : matches) {
                std::cout << match << std::endl;
        }
}
```

As far as converting `027` into a number, you could use `atoi` (from `cstdlib`) like you mentioned, but this will store the value `27`, not `027`. If you want to keep the `0` prefix, I believe you will need to keep this as a `string`. `match` above is a [`sub_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) so, extract a `string` and convert to a `const char*` for `atoi`:

`int value = atoi(match.str().c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Boost, substitute the proper namespace and it should work.

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator SITR;

SITR start = str.begin();
SITR end   = str.end();

boost::regex NumRx("\\d+"); 
boost::smatch m;

while ( boost::regex_search ( start, end, m, NumRx ) )
{
    int val = atoi( m[0].str().c_str() )
    start = m[0].second;
}
```

Comment: Who was asking for boost actually?

Comment: Something different using boost ??

Comment: `std::regex` as already mentioned?? (especially when this question was tagged c++11)

Comment: Feel free to fix my post.